expo-router/_ctx.ios.js:Invalid call at line 2: process.env.EXPO_ROUTER_APP_ROOT
I'm trying to test create-expo-app@latest but it doesn't work when do npx expo start with following error.
iOS Bundling failed 4326ms node_modules/expo-router/entry.js (929 modules)
error: node_modules/expo-router/_ctx.ios.js: node_modules/expo-router/_ctx.ios.js:Invalid call at line 2: process.env.EXPO_ROUTER_APP_ROOT


I just follow instructions in https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/create-a-project/ but failed.
There are few solutions like adding process.env.EXPO_ROUTER_APP_ROOT in babel.config file or something but nothing works..
What can I do? This is the simplest sample but doesn't work!

I have this exact problem, found the solution?

In case someone gets this error, the solution for me was to add index.js file as mentioned here: https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/troubleshooting/
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import { ExpoRoot } from 'expo-router';

// Must be exported or Fast Refresh won't update the context
export function App() {
  const ctx = require.context('./app');
  return <ExpoRoot context={ctx} />;
}

registerRootComponent(App);

But also I needed to change main to "index.js" in package.json
"main": "index.js",

